# MS Azure/Google S Suite User Provisioning/Attribute Mapping

Tags: g-suite, entra-id

I'm using MS Azure to sync/provision my users with Google.  It's working fine except for I need to sync the Azure email attribute with a Google user email alias, as users are set for SSO using their UPN and not email address.  Can someone tell me how to edit the mappings in MS Azure to map the attribute?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this should be already the default setup, where email in Azure AD is mapped to Google email alias.

The setup docs for the provisioning: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-provisioning-tutorial

The setup docs for SSO: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-tutorial